# Summing Values From Calculated Column From Distinct Rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2014

I have data in the following format.

`Column 1` and `Value` from the database.  I use a `LEFT()` function to extract `Column 2`.  Where I need help is to sum the values from the newly calculated `Column 2` and list the sums a new column.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/WNgkU.png]

Any help is appreciated.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Basically, you seem to want an aggregation with a function for the aggregation key:

```
select left(column1, 1), sum(value)
from t
group by left(column1, 1);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve it using **Windows Functions**

Try the following query

```
SELECT column1
, SUBSTRING(column1,1,1) as [calculated column 2]   
,value
, SUM(value) OVER(PARTITION BY SUBSTRING(column1,1,1)  ) 
FROM table1
```

And you can also use `LEFT(Column1,1)` instead of `SUBSTRING(column1,1,1)` ([String Functions](http://www.riptutorial.com/sql-server/example/14341/substring))

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT *
    ,CalculatedColumn2 = LEFT(Column1,1)
    ,Value
    ,CalculatedSum = SUM(Value) OVER (PARTITION BY LEFT(Column1,1))
FROM
    Table
```

While Gordon's answer get's you the SUM if you want it per row you can use a partitioned window Function such as SUM() OVER.

Comment: Thank you!  This worked wonderfully!  Have a good Thanksgiving!

Comment: @Nich your welcome. If your all set don't forget to up vote the answers that helped you and accept one so others know you got your question taken care of and reputation points get awarded. Happy Thanksgiving to you too!

Answer (score 1):

Get the first character from `column1` using `LEFT` function and use that result set as a sub-query and find the sum of `value` column group by the new column.

**Query**

```
SELECT t.[column2], SUM(t.[value]) as [value] FROM(
    SELECT [column1], LEFT([column1], 1) AS [column2], [value]
    FROM [your_table_name]
)t
GROUP BY t.[column2];
```

Answer (score 1):

Add `computed persisted column` which can contain values from left(column1, 1). You shloudn't repeat your code.

```
alter table tbl add newcomputedcol column (left(column1, 1)) persisted
```

Use grouped subqry or use over clause:

```
select 
   *, 
   sum(value) over() over(partition by newcomputedcol) SumPerNewComputedCol
from tbl
```

Your new persisted column can be indexed, your qry can be added into view.